# Entity Framework 4.1 and Business Logic Layer

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, design-patterns

I am trying to use Entity Framework 4.0 for an asp .net application. As of now, it will be old style code behind files and without unit testing but in the future I may use MVP and unit testing but as of now, it is not a concern for me. I am using Database First approach. Here is a model ( I could not post image as I need reputation to post image)

- Table: Application (ApplicationID, Name, Hidden)
- Table: User (UserID, ApplicationID, Username, IsActive)
- Table: Role (RoleID, ApplicationID, Name)
- Table: UserRole (UserRoleID, RoleID, UserID)

I have been reading a lot about Entity Framework and how to use it but still could not get a very basic idea about some stuff. Where do I write a code like this for Application, User, Role, UserRole etc?

```
public List<Application> GetAllUnhiddenApplications()
{
    List<Application> applist = null;
    using (CustomAppsPortalEntities ctx = new CustomAppsPortalEntities())
    {
        applist = (from app in ctx.Applications
            where app.Hidden == false
            orderby app.Name
            select app).ToList();
    }
    return applist;
}
```

I have separated Context and Entities in separate projects Project.Data and Project.Entities respectively. My question is if above code belongs to BLL (class name ApplicationBLL) or DLL (ApplicationDLL)? From past 2 days, I have been searching lots of SO questions, blogs, tutorials and different people have different approach. Here is my dilemma.

If I put the code in Data layer, then in the business layer, I have to create a "pass through" function like ApplicationBLL.GetAllUnhiddenApplications which will return ApplidationDLL.GetAllUnhiddenApplications. I have to repeat it for all the queries and basically whole BLL will eventually become "pass through" layer for DLL. Can you give me a concrete example of what Business layer will be used for in reference to above schema?

If I put the code in Business layer, then linq will exist in Business layer which eventually will be converted to SQL by Entity Framework so it is like exposing query logic to Business Layer.

**Our Environment**
Our environment is fast paced and want to complete this project as soon as possible with the moderately proper approach where there is a separate layer but in the future when we find time, we may refactor the code and make it really robust but it is not a concern as of now but if the time permits, we want to implement best practices right now versus refactoring code in the future.

Comment: This is the kind of question that can only be answered when you know the whole picture. Maybe it helps to consider the EF context _and_ all mapped classes (i.e. the conceptual model) as data layer. They may look like a domain layer and even be used as such in many cases, but _primarily_ they are data layer. The question what to do now and what can wait is really impossible to answer. I'm afraid you have to draw the line between lean-and-mean and YAGNI yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code would typically be in the BL layer.  Using linq in your BL layer is fine because your linq queries are still data persistence ignorant.  From linq queries perspective, it's querying objects from entity framework.

What you might be missing is a "repository pattern" and "unit of work patter".  The repository pattern acts as an interface to entity framework.  It allows you to interact with EF objects like in-memory collections.  Typically I keep all repositories in one project and reference accordingly.  To give you an example, Microsoft Spain provides a n-tierd example,

http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/

It's very over engineered, but I believe it will give you what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Many people argue that EF IS the DLL.

Typically, I set my projects up something like this...

```
  D --->  Presentation Layers (MVC, WCF, WinForms, etc)
  A               |     
  T               V
  A --->  Business Logic Layer
                  |
  M               V
  O --->  Entity Layer / DLL
  D
  E
  L
```

The Data Models project is really just a collection of POCO's that can be used in any of the other projects.

The Entity Layer is your EDMX file and Context.

It should be fine to access the context in the Entity/DLL layer, since .Net has abstracted everything out for you.

If you think about it, the whole reason to abstract out a DLL layer is so that you can change databases without having to change the BLL.  With EF, you can change a database in 1 step and everything should still work.... as long as your schema stays the same.